# How to use "echo" on Linux for HTTP POST/PUT request

Tags: linux, shell, unix, echo

I have searched a lot but cannot find any answer to this query. I would like to POST to a URL using  echo. Is this possible? Is there any other command which can be used for this?

My use cases:
1. POST text
2. POST file

Answer (score 2):

The tool you're looking for is [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

To post a file you would do something like:

```
$ curl -XPOST --data-binary @file http://url
```

where "file" is the location of the file you want to send and url is the url you want to post to.  If you need to specify the content type add the relevant header, e.g. if you want to post json add  `-H"Content-Type: application/json"`

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe `echo` to some command able to connect to a given port on some IP. `nc` is such a command. For example :

echo "GET /" | nc www.blablablabla.com 80

`curl` (has mentioned by @MrWiggles) is a tool that lets you talk to servers in many different protocols (particularly HTTP).

`w3c` is a tool similar to `curl`. (part of `libwww`).

And it is relatively easy to build such with scripting langages (python, ruby, etc).